# show captcha after few login attempts

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

i am using laravel 5.6 and php 7

as you all know captcha is boring but safe so i want to show captcha to the guest after 5 attempts of login to laravel app

i don't want to use laravel throating

i want to store ip address in data base and when attempts become more than 5 captcha appear

i have make this code

```
    $IPaddress = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    $usser = new Logs;
    $usser->ip_address = $IPaddress;
    $usser->attempts = $usser->attempts+1;
    $useer->save();
```

i have make the data base with ip and attempts rows and columns

but i don't know where to put this code

Comment: A service class that's injected into the AuthController?  Not really sure that code will work though since you're creating a new instance and somehow expecting `$user->attempts` to be some value greater than 0?

Comment: i set the defult value in database to be 0 so 0+1 =1

Comment: Right, and the next attempt would be 0+1 and the next attempt 0+1 and so on..

Comment: did you see  $useer->save(); ?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to store it in the database ? you can also use the build in [RateLimiter](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Cache/RateLimiter.html)

Comment: @Dark.Attacker, yes, but you're creating a new object everytime, not fetching one from the db.